# ExtJs 3.4 : Set tool tip for combo box

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, tooltip

I have an `ExtJs` combo box as following. I am using ExtJS 3.4. I need to set hover text for this combo box. i.e. when user hover over this combo box, message text should appear.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        store : driverStore,
        displayField : 'dName',
        valueField : 'dName',
        fieldLabel : 'Driver Name',
        id : 'drivercombo',
        allowBlank : false,
        typeAhead : true,
        forceSelection : true,
        mode : 'local',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        selectOnFocus : true,
        editable : false,
        hidden : false,
        disabled : true,
        minChars : 1,
        hideLabel : true,
        style : 'marginleft:10px',
        //width : 147,
        emptyText : 'Driver Name',
        flex : 1
    });
```

I know there is a way to set this tool tip messages for combo box items of the drop down menu. But I don't want it. I want a tool tip for my combo box.

How should I do that ?

Comment: there is no event for hover, no chance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create `Ext.ToolTip` in listener for `combobox` `render` event and as `tooltip` target you can define combobox element.

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    mode: 'local',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: [
            'myId',
            'displayText'
        ],
        data: [[1, 'item1'], [2, 'item2']]
    }),
    listeners: {
        render: function(c) {
          new Ext.ToolTip({
            target: c.getEl(),
            html: 'Tooltip content'
          });
        }
    },    
    valueField: 'myId',
    displayField: 'displayText'
});
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2q6**

Comment: Thanx Akatum. This is really what I want.

Comment: Aktum, can your explain why your need to put tooltip in the render listener? Yes, it will not work other way by i can not undersend why.

Comment: It is because you have to bind tooltip to element which is in DOM. So in this case you have to bind tooltip to top level element representing this combobox component. And this element does not exists before than combobox is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the Listener of combo box it worked at my side.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        mode: 'local',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            id: 0,
            fields: ['id', 'displaytext'],
            data: [
                [1, 'Vinayak']
            ]
        }),
        listeners: {
            render: function(c) {
                 Ext.QuickTips.register({ target: this.getEl(), 
                 text: 'Tooltip Data' });
            }
        },
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'displaytext'
    });

});
```

You have to write

`Ext.QuickTips.init()`; on `Ext.Ready`