# extjs 3.4 add tool tip in from field

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip, extjs3

Hi I have some form fields and I'm trying to add tool tip. But it is not working. This is my fields,

```
var importForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
             //html: "<p>Imgae source: <b>img</b> folder in root directory</p>",
            url: '/plugin/ImageImport/admin/import',
            monitorValid: true,
            labelWidth: 175,
            frame: true,
            title: 'Image Import',
            width: 250,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            defaults: { allowBlank: false },
            items:[
              { fieldLabel: 'Source Folder Path', name: 'imgSourcePath', id:'imgSourcePath' },
              {
                  xtype: 'combo',
                  name: 'folderId',
                  fieldLabel: 'Target Folder',
                  mode: 'local',
                  store: valuesDir,
                  displayField:'key',
                  valueField: 'id',
                  width: 'auto',
                  triggerAction: 'all',
                  emptyText:'Select Folder...',
                  id:'folderId',
                  selectOnFocus:true,
                  allowBlank: false,
                  editable: false,
                },

              {
                  xtype: 'combo',
                  name: 'transformation',
                  fieldLabel: 'Image Transformations',
                  mode: 'local',
                  store: values,
                  displayField:'name',
                  valueField: 'name',
                  width: 'auto',
                  triggerAction: 'all',
                  emptyText:'Select Transformation...',
                  id:'transformation',
                  selectOnFocus:true,
                  allowBlank: false,
                  editable: false,

                },


                   ],
```

And at the end of my code I'm trying to add tool tip,

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    new Ext.ToolTip({
    target: 'imgSourcePath',
    html: 'A very simple tooltip'
        });

 new Ext.ToolTip({
    target: 'folderId',
    html: 'A very simple tooltip'
        });

 new Ext.ToolTip({
    target: 'transformation',
    html: 'A very simple tooltip'
        });

 Ext.QuickTips.init();
});
```

I tried qtip as well but that also not working.like,

```
 { fieldLabel: 'Source Folder Path', name: 'imgSourcePath', id:'imgSourcePath', qtip: 'This is tool tip' },
```

Please help me someone ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29675846/3688026

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this issue to know how to put it on comboBox [ExtJs 3.4 : Set tool tip for combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228172/extjs-3-4-set-tool-tip-for-combo-box)

Hope this help.